# send a variable to the view with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have a function, that count the visits of my web site, I tried to send a variable into the view but it doesn't work, the variable has to pass trought a file that contents the templates. When the variable I pass directly to the view it works, but other way doesn't. Please help me. Thanks.

in the controller

```
$query = $object->Searcher_visits();
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
while ($query->result()) {
$current_date = $list['date'] = $query->date; 
$count = $obj_forum->visits($current_date);
$list2['num'] = $count->num;
$list2['current_date'] = $current_date;
}
}
$data['list2'] = $list2;
$data['list'] = $lis;
$this->load->view('template/general_template/template', $data);
```

in the view (this view is the left menu)

```
<table border="1" width="250px" cellpading="5px" cellspacing="5px">';
<tr><td>FECHA</td><td>VISITAS</td></tr>';
tr><td><?php echo $list2['current_date']; ?></td>
<td align="right"><?php echo $list2['num'];?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

the template

```
<?php
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('banner');
$this->load->view('left_menu');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass the variable to your template, but you need the variable in the left_menu view, but you don't give the variable to that view. A quick fix would be just pass the variable along from within your template:

```
<?php
$data = array($list1, $list2);
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('banner');
$this->load->view('left_menu', $data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Controller code

$query = $object->Searcher_visits();
if ($query->num_rows > 0){
   $data['list2'] = $query->result();
   $data['list'] = $obj_forum;
}
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('banner');
$this->load->view('left_menu',$data);
```

//view page

```
<table border="1" width="250px" cellpading="5px" cellspacing="5px">
  <tr>
     <td>FECHA</td>
     <td>VISITAS</td>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($list2 as $ex2){?>
  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $ex2->date; ?></td>
      <td align="right"><?php echo $list->visits($ex2->date);?></td>
  </tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that $data['list2'] is an array. Since an array should iterated even though it has a single value on each array key. a foreach will solve your problem.

```html
<table border="1" width="250px" cellpading="5px" cellspacing="5px">';
<tr><td>FECHA</td><td>VISITAS</td></tr>';
tr><td><?php echo $list2['current_date']; ?></td>
<td align="right"><?php echo $list2['num'];?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

should be like this:

```html
<table border="1" width="250px" cellpading="5px" cellspacing="5px">;
  <tr>
    <td>FECHA</td>
    <td>VISITAS</td>
  </tr>;
  <?php foreach($list2 as $list):?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <?= $list->current_date ?>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
      <?=$list->num?>
    </td>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the problem is that the variable its not recognize in the view   
                                                                                                                    A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: list2
Filename: left_menu.php
Line Number: 69